# Proplem with get element id ( Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null )

Tags: javascript, ajax

i want to get some value from div and send it to database, i wrote it and it worked at my localhost but when i uploaded source on my host it stopped working...

this error i get in console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null index.php:700
request.onreadystatechange
```

ajax on same page where divs are

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
// create the XMLHttpRequest object, according browser
function get_XmlHttp() {
  // create the variable that will contain the instance of the XMLHttpRequest object (initially with null value)
  var xmlHttp = null;

  if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {       // for Forefox, IE7+, Opera, Safari, ...
    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else if(window.ActiveXObject) {   // for Internet Explorer 5 or 6
    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

  return xmlHttp;
}

// sends data to a php file, via POST, and displays the received answer
function ajaxrequest(php_file, tagID) {
  var request =  get_XmlHttp();     // call the function for the XMLHttpRequest instance

  // create pairs index=value with data that must be sent to server
  var  the_data = 'pg='+document.getElementById('template').innerHTML;
  var  the_data2 = 'memid='+document.getElementById('memid').innerHTML;
  var  the_data3 = 'proid='+document.getElementById('proid').innerHTML;
  var  the_data4 = 'taipei='+document.getElementById('taipei').innerHTML;

  request.open("POST", php_file, true);         // set the request

  // adds  a header to tell the PHP script to recognize the data as is sent via POST
  request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  var post_data = the_data + '&' + the_data2 + '&' + the_data3 + '&' + the_data4;

  request.send(post_data);      // calls the send() method with datas as parameter
  // Check request status
  // If the response is received completely, will be transferred to the HTML tag with tagID
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      document.getElementById(tagID).innerHTML = request.responseText;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

divs

```
<div id="template"> some html here </div>
<div id="memid" style="display:none;">4</div>
<div id="proid" style="display:none;">55</div>
<div id="taipei" style="display:none;">sav</div>
```

button

```
<button value="sasasasasa" onclick="ajaxrequest('temp1.php', 'context')"></button>
```

Comment: Which line in that wall of code is line 700? What do you see when you walk through this with the debugger built into the browser?

Comment: Why is it tagged java and jquery-ajax, since you don't use java and jquery?

Comment: And it's probably worth mentioning that you really need to use `encodeURIComponent` when sending URI-encoded data to the server (e.g., on your `the_data`, `the_data2`, etc. variables -- technically the names used before the `=` as well, but you can get away without for simple names using only the 26 English letters, digits, and a couple of other characters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming line 700 is

```
document.getElementById(tagID).innerHTML = request.responseText;
```

...then you clearly don't have an element with the `id` in `tagID`, which according to the example button you've shown, would be `"context"`. And indeed, you haven't shown any HTML that defines an element with the `id` `"context"`.

Comment: thanks i forgot to add it when i was moving it to my hosting XD